# Fragment IllegalStateException when placing inside dialogfragment

Tags: java, android, mono

When I place a fragment inside dialogfragment without using activity I am getting an IllegalStateException. My design is not to use activity. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Code snippet:

```
popUpFragment = this;
popUpFragment.dismissPopUp += DismissPopUpDialog;
dialog = new PopUpDialogFragment(popUpFragment, this.GetString(Resource.String.signin_btn_title), HeaderButton.Close, this.Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.Tablet_Popup_Width), this.Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.Tablet_Signin_Height), true);
dialog.Show(this.Activity.SupportFragmentManager, "test dialog");
```

This above code has been used inside the constructor of the fragment. The exception I am getting is:

```
06-26 21:58:17.505: W/dalvikvm(4696): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
06-26 21:58:17.505: W/dalvikvm(4696):              in Lgrocery/droid/fragments/HomeScreenFragment;.n_onClick:(Landroid/view/View;)V (GetMethodID)
06-26 21:58:17.505: W/dalvikvm(4696): Pending exception is:
06-26 21:58:17.505: I/dalvikvm(4696): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SignInFragment{53aad3b8} not attached to Activity
06-26 21:58:17.505: I/dalvikvm(4696):   (raw stack trace not found)
06-26 21:58:17.509: I/dalvikvm(4696): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
06-26 21:58:17.509: I/dalvikvm(4696):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xa62e54b0 self=0xb7aea500
06-26 21:58:17.509: I/dalvikvm(4696):   | sysTid=4696 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1216605120
06-26 21:58:17.509: I/dalvikvm(4696):   | schedstat=( 3374948563 913984594 3593 ) utm=283 stm=54 core=0
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   #00  pc 0008f4ad  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   #01  pc 00073efa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   #02  pc 00074024  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   #03  pc 0003879a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   #04  pc 0003d788  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   #05  pc 00029d28  <unknown>
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   at grocery.droid.fragments.HomeScreenFragment.n_onClick(Native Method)
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   at grocery.droid.fragments.HomeScreenFragment.onClick(HomeScreenFragment.java:81)
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-26 21:58:17.525: I/dalvikvm(4696):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment and DialogFragment must use Activity to implement Have the activity pass the information along to the other fragment or you can use a AlertDialog.Builder instead. Take a look here: [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)